# Kolmogorov Probability Theory Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, math-history

I'm reading [link: Foundations of theory of probability - Kolmogorov](https://archive.org/details/foundationsofthe00kolm) and have some questions regarding this historical text.  I'm a bit stuck, so any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

In the axioms below it is stated that "*F* a set of subsets of $E$" and per Axiom III. "to each set $A$ in *F*".  Therefore it's my understanding field *F* includes a subset of the power set $\mathcal{P}(E)$.  Is this the correct understanding?

[image: axioms]

He then states in (8) below that the system of sets $\mathcal{U}$ forms a decomposition and the sets $A_1, A_2, ..., A_i$ do not intersect.  It's my understanding a decomposition is also known as a partition.  I'm confused because there are earlier statements that sets $A_i$ form a subset of the power set, in which these sets would possibly intersect, while later in item 8 he states that "the sets, do not intersect, in pairs." Why the conflict or am I missing something?
[image: system U]

Finally based on above I'm trying to understand what's expressed on on Page 9 below.  What is independence?  Can anyone guide through this page?  I understand that each experiment has a set of decompositions, however am confused because based on earlier statements I assume the decompositions to be the same every time, specifically for the power set.

[image: Page 9]

Can anyone explain the following form?  The confusing part to me, is if the $P(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ sets do not intersect, i.e. they are mutually exclusive, there is still probability to the right side of the question.  This seems like an inequality.

[image: x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here $\cal F$ is a subset of the power set of $E$. In other words, the types of things in $\cal F$ are sets, and the elements of those sets are in elements from $E$. Alternatively, everything in $\cal F$ is in $\mathcal P(E)$ but not necessarily the other way around.

A decomposition $\cal U$ is a *special* subset of the power set in which the sets in $\cal U$ do not intersect each other at all, and they cover the entire set $E$. Not every subset of the power set is a decomposition, but every decomposition is a subset of the power set.

Finally, independence DOES NOT mean disjoint/mutually exclusive. The definition of independence is exactly that the probability of the intersection equals the products of the probabilities; i.e. if that equation is true, then we can call those experiments "mutually independent", and if the equation is not true, those experiments are not "mutually independent". There is not really an intuitive picture you can draw in your head of when two things are independent.

Lastly, I'm not sure that learning probability theory from Kolmogorov's book is the best idea. I think it would be much easier to learn it from a more modern book with more modern/more intuitive notation first, then come back to Kolmogorov. However, I do not claim to know your situation, so of course this is just my two cents.

Personally I started my probability journey from [measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf](http://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf) (chapter 2,3 and chapter 12 are the key parts). A classic book on pure probability theory would be [colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/…](https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/billingsley.pdf), which I think is pretty good. I don't know what level you want to study the subject at, but these are where I started.

Comment: Thanks. I’m still confused by the last equality posted. Is that not set intersection inside the P()? If so, and the sets are disjoint, that inequality will not hold. P(0) = 0 yet the right side will be positive probability.

Comment: @Nick yes, as I said, if the equality fails (as in your case), the events are not mutually independent. You've discovered that if the events are disjoint, they are not mutually independent.

Comment: I think where I'm confused is the last equality labeled Definition I.  For example if the set of elementary events or sample space is $\{H, T\}$ for heads and tails, where each has a probability of 1/2.   If $A_q1_1 = A_q2_2 = \{H\}$, then $P(A_q1_1 A_q2_2) = 1/2$, while $P(A_q1_1) * P(A_q2_2) = 1/4$.  This indicates that heads occurred in two experiments.  The equality fails, so these events are not mutually independent?  Do you have an example?  Any guidance here appreciated.

Comment: In regards to this book, I started reading it after it was referenced in Berger.  I looked at Berger and also Feller, however was concerned that I needed a teacher to guide me vs self study with those books.  Very wordy.  Any recommendations appreciated.

Comment: @Nick Frankly, I do not understand all the subscripts, and the word "experiment", so I can't verify for sure that your example is indeed valid. Personally I started my probability journey from http://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf (chapter 2,3 and chapter 12 are the key parts). A classic book on pure probability theory would be https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/billingsley.pdf, which I think is pretty good. I don't know what level you want to study the subject at, but these are where I started.

Comment: @Nick also, if you do pursue the books I recommended and want some more resources, I may be able to give you some notes on the subject.

Comment: the word experiment or the gothic U is defined as an "Experiment U consists of determining which of the events $A_1 A_2,...,A_n$ occurs.   $A_1 A_2,...,A_n$ are the possible results."  I'm still a bit confused by some of the notation.  Do you know if $p_{q1 q2 ... qn}$ is a set of probabilities or a single probability?  Also a bit confused by the sum function right after this marked (1), linked to the previous question.

Comment: My earlier question you mention the subscripts are not understood I will reformat here.  I'm was trying to use a coin toss example and substitute it into (2) to see the outcome.  I suspect there is no mutual independence with the coin toss because each experiment will be disjoint?